# Vagrant Gitlab installation failed

Tags: ubuntu, chef-infra, vagrant, gitlab

I'm trying install this https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-vagrant-vm dev environment for GitLab.

When I follow installation instruction - I get following errors in terminal, on my ubuntu(x64) machine:

```
[2013-04-14T22:59:27+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers

[2013-04-14T22:59:27+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete

[2013-04-14T22:59:32+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-stacktrace.out

[2013-04-14T22:59:32+00:00] FATAL: NoMethodError: gem_package[rvm] (rvm::default line 21) had an error: NoMethodError: undefined method `full_name' for nil:NilClass
Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.

I find the chef-stacktrace.out file:

Generated at Sun Apr 14 22:59:32 +0000 2013
NoMethodError: gem_package[rvm] (rvm::default line 21) had an error: NoMethodError: undefined method `full_name$

/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:134:in `gather_dependencies'

/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:134:in `map'

/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:134:in `gather_dependencies'

/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:268:in `install'

/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/provider/package/rubygems.rb:169:in `inst$

/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/provider/package/rubygems.rb:192:in `with$

/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/provider/package/rubygems.rb:168:in `inst$

/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/provider/package/rubygems.rb:103:in `with$

/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/provider/package/rubygems.rb:167:in `inst$

/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/provider/package/rubygems.rb:476:in `inst$

/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/provider/package.rb:81:in `action_install'

/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:63:in `call'

/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:63:in `converge!'

/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:61:in `each'

/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:61:in `converge!'

/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/provider.rb:136:in `converge'

/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/provider.rb:125:in `run_action'

/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/resource.rb:593:in `run_action'

/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/rvm/recipes/default.rb:23:in `from_file'

/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/cookbook_version.rb:558:in `load_recipe'

/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/language_include_recipe.rb:46:in `l$

/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/language_include_recipe.rb:33:in `i$

/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/language_include_recipe.rb:27:in `e$

/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/language_include_recipe.rb:27:in `i$

/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/rvm/recipes/user_install.rb:20:in `from_file'

/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/cookbook_version.rb:558:in `load_recipe'

/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/language_include_recipe.rb:46:in `l$

/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/language_include_recipe.rb:33:in `i$

/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/language_include_recipe.rb:27:in `e$

/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/language_include_recipe.rb:27:in `i$

/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/rvm/recipes/user.rb:20:in `from_file'

/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/cookbook_version.rb:558:in `load_recipe'

/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/language_include_recipe.rb:46:in `l$

/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/language_include_recipe.rb:33:in `i$

/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/language_include_recipe.rb:27:in `e$

/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/language_include_recipe.rb:27:in `i$

/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/run_context.rb:79:in `load'

/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/run_context.rb:75:in `each'

/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/run_context.rb:75:in `load'

/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/client.rb:198:in `setup_run_context'

/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/client.rb:418:in `do_run'

/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/client.rb:176:in `run'

/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/application/solo.rb:230:in `run_applicati$

/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/application/solo.rb:218:in `loop'

/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/application/solo.rb:218:in `run_applicati$

/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/application.rb:70:in `run'

/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/chef-solo:25

/opt/vagrant_ruby/bin/chef-solo:19:in `load'

/opt/vagrant_ruby/bin/chef-solo:19
```

Comment: Sounds like an internal error in one of the dependencies required to setup GitLab, maybe you should report the error there? And the stacktrace.out file is located in the VM not on your host - did you look there?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I attach log output to question

Comment: Maybe you should report this potential bug including stacktrace here: https://github.com/fnichol/chef-rvm/issues I don't think it's your or your environment's fault

Comment: If you just want to install GitLab, there is an installer and a pre-packaged VMware image available here => http://bitnami.com/stack/gitlab. GitLab has been thru tremendous changes 4.x -> 5.x. I'd recommend following the installation guide to manually set it up if you have never done that before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem and it turned out that RVM hadn't installed properly. In my case, a firewall was getting in the way. Obviously your root cause may be different, but check your log to make sure that your VM can access [RubyGems.org](http://rubygems.org/), and that RVM was properly installed.